# ASP.Net MVC C# two viewmodels within another viewmodel - how to reference in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to follow suggested best practice, by using ViewModels.

In my forum app, I want to post a list of posts, and at the bottom of the screen, add a textbox so replies can be posted.

So in my mind, I need a ViewModel for the Posts list, and a ViewModel for the Reply to be posted (TopicId and Content).

Therefore, I think I need to combine these two ViewModels together in a third ViewModel, and in my View, iterate over the Posts part of the ViewModel, and then at the bottom, create a form, where I have the Reply part of the ViewModel - and the Postback sends just the ReplyViewModel to the controller.

My ViewModels are:

```
 public class PostViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfTopic { get; set; }
}

public class ReplyViewModel
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class PostListAndReplyVM
{
    public List<PostViewModel> PostViewModel { get; set; }
    public ReplyViewModel ReplyViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I populate the PostViewModel, then create an empty ReplyViewModel, then combine them in a PostListAndReplyVM:

```
//
    // GET: /Post/List/5
    public ActionResult List(int id = 0)
    {
        // Populate PostViewModel

        var post = db.Posts.Include(x => x.Topic)
              .Select(p => new PostViewModel
              {
                  PostId = p.TopicId,
                  Title = p.Title,
                  Description = p.Content,
                  DateOfTopic = p.DateOfPost,
                  Author = p.Author
              }
             ).ToList();

        // Populate empty ReplyViewModel

        ReplyViewModel prvm = new ReplyViewModel();
        prvm.Content = "";
        prvm.TopicId = id;

        // Combine two viewmodels into a third, to send to the controller

        PostListAndReplyVM pvm = new PostListAndReplyVM();
        pvm.ReplyViewModel = prvm;
        pvm.PostViewModel = post;

        // Return combined ViewModel to the view

        return View(pvm);
    }
```

Then in my view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM>

<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostId)
    </th>
....
....
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostId)
    </td>
```

How do I refer to the two separate ViewModels within the **PostListAndReplyVM** posted to the view. eg. if I think it should be something like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemitem.PostViewModel.PostId)
```

...but that gives the error:

**'centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM' does not contain a definition for 'PostId' and no extension method 'PostId' accepting a first argument of type 'centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM' could be found**

And for the list part:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PostViewModel)
```

...gives an error of:

**'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'PostViewModel' and no extension method 'PostViewModel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found**

I'm sure I'm missing something simple - thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made an error on your view, you return a PostListAndReplyVM on your controller and your view reference an IEnumerable of PostListAndReplyVM.

You have to change the declarated model in your view

```
@model centreforum.Models.PostListAndReplyVM
```

Hope it's help

Comment: Hi - that makes sense, thank you - but now when I try to reference: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostViewModel.PostId) I get the error:  'System.Collections.Generic.List<centreforum.Models.PostViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'PostId' and no extension method 'PostId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<centreforum.Models.PostViewModel>' could be found - so my view still isn't correct - thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Hi, model.PostViewModel is a collection, you have to loop on it before !